# In which beta-elimination reaction do the structures of the carbocations formed influence the reactivity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I believe there is a mistake. If we go back to the mechanisms, E2 does not go through a carbocation. So, there should not be any impact.

E1 does however. So, E1 should be circled. Is there a missing point or argument in my logic.